# Meteor : Iron-Router error request entity too large

Tags: node.js, express, meteor, websocket, iron-router

I'm trying to send data from a node js server to a meteor app. In the node js app I'm doing this :

```
axios.put('http://localhost:3000/api/project/'+id,{"data" :data, "idExtractor":idExtractor, "version":getVersion()})
```

where data is a string of the XML given by our server

And in my meteor app I'm receiving this on a server route in lib/Router.js file, but when the data is too large, the meteor server gives me the errors "socket hang up" and "request entity too large".

I tried solutions from the issues of Iron Router on github, doing the following code in the Router.js file.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Router.onBeforeAction(Iron.Router.bodyParser.raw({ 
    type: '/', 
    only: ['creditReferral'], 
    verify: function(req, res, body){
      req.rawBody = body.toString(); 
    },
    where: 'server'
  }));
  Router.onBeforeAction(Iron.Router.bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit : '10mb'
  }));
  Router.onBeforeAction(Iron.Router.bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit : '10mb' 
  }), 
  { where: 'server'});
}
```

I tried to put it before all routes definitions, before server routes, after all routes, I also tried to put it in server/main.js in the startup block.

I also tried to change these limits in the node server with this

```
express.urlencoded({
  limit: '10mb', 
  extended: true, 
  type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
})
express.json({
  limit: '10mb', 
  strict: false, 
  type: "application/json"
})
```

and this

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit :'10mb' }));
```

But I always have the same problem, all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After trying many solutions, I fixed this problem with this in my Router.js :

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Router.onBeforeAction( Iron.Router.bodyParser.json({
        limit: '50mb'
    }), {
        except: ['creditReferral'],
        where: 'server'
    });
    Router.onBeforeAction( Iron.Router.bodyParser.raw({
        type: '*/*',
        only: ['creditReferral'],
        verify: function(req, res, body){
            req.rawBody = body.toString();
        },
        where: 'server'}));
}
```

This fixed the entity too large error, but because the data is xml in this request, I couldn't directly parse it to json, so I needed to change my

```
var json = JSON.parse(this.request.body)
```

to the following :

```
var stringify = JSON.stringify(this.request.body);
var json = JSON.parse(stringify);
```

and it worked. Hope this could help someone having the same issue.